# How get parent object reference in python with out passing argument 'self'?

Tags: python, class, object, reference

Look at the following example:

```py
class People:
    def __init__(self, home):
        self.home = home
        self.name = 'Ankit'

        self.set_add()

    def set_add(self):
        self.add = self.home.add


class Home:
    def __init__(self):
        self.add = 'Jaipur, Rajasthan'

    def get_add(self):
        people = People(self)
        print(people.add)
        pass

home = Home()
home.get_add()
```

Here I have to pass the `self` argument to access the parent object reference.
Is there any method in which I can access the parent object reference without passing any argument.

**EDIT: if you didn't get it**
Look at the `__init__` function in the class `People`, here I am assigning the reference of the object of that class in which the object of the class 'People' is created and then in `set_add` method the `add` of the object of that class in which the object of the `People` class is created.

All these things are possible because I am passing the reference of the object of that class in which the object of class `People` is created as you can see in `get_add` method in `Home` class while creating object of `People` class I am passing `self` that will be reference of the object of `Home` class whenever object will be created of `Home` class.

But what I want I don't want to pass any argument. So is there any method by which I can do the same without passing any argument while creating an object in other class.

Comment: Can you maybe give an example of what kind of syntax you would like to have? Or some use case for it? I'm not sure what you mean by "the parent object reference". In Python, objects do not have a "parent" by default, or anything like that, so if you want to establish a relationship between two objects you need to keep the references somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You've passed `self` (the instantiated `Home()` object, `home` in this case) as the value of the `home` argument of the initilizer of class `Home`.

The `self` i.e. the instance is passed implicitly, and you've again used `self` making the class initilizer like:

```
People.__init__(self, self)
```

Also, there is no parent-child between the classes as their no relationship between them, what you've used is like composition. Perhaps you meant to pass `self.add` (seemingly an address):

```
people = People(self.add)
```

Again there are many unclear stuff in your class definitions, without fully understanding them it's hard to get to a proper conclusion.